# Is there an interface type that is implemented by various cli streams?

Tags: c#, .net

I was writing some support functions for MemoryStream but i figured that since the same methods would also work for FileStream and NetworkStream, I might as well set the argument type to an interface that I assume all of these share. I couldn't find out what that interface is called though. IStream from System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes appears to be something else.

Comment: Have you considered writing `MemoryStream` in Visual Studio then right-click=>Go to definition to see what it inherits from and what it implements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They doesn't implement same interface, but all of them inherit abstract [System.IO.Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx) class.